# How to call helper in magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying to call my helper in block file but i can not load helper. I found following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Product_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code.

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call the helper file in controller or block, use the below code:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product');
```

If you call the helper file in phtml file, use the below code:

```
$helper = $this->helper('catalog/product');
```